# How to handle data storage/pass values between pages in Tizen SDK?

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

How to handle cookie or data storage in tizen sdk with javascript. I'm looking for options to store my session details and the authentication details to validate, in all other pages.

My Scenario is I'm having an html/javascript application which will contact java servlet through AJAX for all the authentication and search functionality. In all the service calls i'm checking the session and the cookie to validate the login status of the user. First page "index.html" holds the login screen and navigate to another html page present in /WebContent folder on successful authentication. I couldn't able to access any information (Session/Cookie) in the second page which is stored through first page.

I'm looking for accessing these values in second page or anyother way to pass values between pages of an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript and HTML now offers the use of localStorages to keep name value pair data:

```
// to store a value
window.localStorage.setItem( 'item_name', item_value);

// to retrieve a value
item_value = window.localStorage.getItem( 'item_name' );

// to delete a storage
window.localStorage.removeItem( 'item_name' );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems to be like the syntax for setItem is window.localStorage.setItem('name',value); and for some reason the deleteItem doesn't seems to work and also when i open the page again it is available(Kind of persistant). I want it to be moved out of memory on closing the app.

Comment: Thanks!!! It seems to be like the syntax for setItem is window.localStorage.setItem('name',value); and for some reason the deleteItem doesn't seems to work. It seems to be like removeItem not deleteItem. And also when i open the page again it is available(Kind of persistant). I want it to be moved out of memory on closing the app. And any Idea also storing the session ?

Comment: Indeed that is removeItem only. Yes it remains persistent, you need to remove the item if you don't want it to exist next time. I'm storing sessions in local storages only.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Web App Widget you should use [Filesystem API](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/filesystem.html) provide by Tizen API to store data.

If you look in Remote inspector help at [Resources Panel](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/web_inspector.htm) it says:

> The Resources panel allows you to inspect resources. You can interact
>   with frames containing resources, such as HTML, JavaScript, CSS,
>   images, and fonts. Additionally, you can also inspect **HTML5 databases,
>   local storage, cookies, and application cache**.

So you can also use one of this to store your data.

You can use jQuery in your Web App and cookies, see here in this answer a plugin:
[cookies with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080745/1577343)

Comment: I've already completed the requirement with the previous solution. I'll try to utilize your solution when i get time. Thanks for providing valuable information.

Comment: @Brun No need to, I've added the answer just to provide information for future reference :)